# Get which Fields are selected in the SOQL Query as query is executed using Database.query method

Tags: apex, soql

I need to fetch data on basis of some conditions, each condition have different set of fields to be fetched from the same object. and those fields are to be displayed on  in vf page.

Insted of writing if-elseif-else tree for various selections, i stored all related queries in a map and i will use **Database.query()** for executing the queries.

Now when one of those queries will be executed, i want to figure out which fields are selected in the query executed.

Comment: You should use Dynamic SOQL queries
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: Surely i will use Dynamic SOQL to execute my query that is stored in map which is string type. But i want to know how to identify the fields being extracted!

Answer (score 3):

New sObject methods like:

```
getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
```

> Returns a map of populated field names and their corresponding values. The map contains only the fields that have been populated in memory for the SObject instance.

Should help accomplish your goal

[sObject Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

Comment: can i use it for List of records

Comment: This do not works for database.query() result

Comment: Just use for each record. It's an sobject method. You really should only need the first record if all records came from same query